# Why my random number game doesn't work right?

Tags: python, python-3.x

guys! I'm new here. Nice to meet you!

I have the following problem. My random number generator always do exactly the same number. I have a guess why it's happening, but I'm not sure. Can you, please, explain what I'm doing wrong and just write some words about my code at all? Thanks!

```
import random


def begin():
    r_num = random.randint(1, 10)
    p_num = int(input('Enter your number: '))
    ch = (r_num, p_num)
    if ch[0] == ch[1]:
        print(ch[0])
        print("You've won! Excellent!")
        play_again = input("Do you want to play again? y/n")
        if play_again == 'y' or play_again == 'Y':
            begin()
        elif play_again == 'n' or play_again == 'N':
            print('Goodbye!')
    elif ch[1] < ch[0]:
        print(ch[0])
        print("Your number is lower than it must be!")
        begin()
    elif ch[1] > ch[0]:
        print(ch[0])
        print("Your number is higher than it must be!")
        begin()


def start():
    gen = input('Print generate to begin playing! \n')
    if gen == 'generate':
        print('Success!')
        begin()
    else:
        print('Fail!')
        start()


print('Welcome to my first Python game! Guess random generated number from 1 to 10!')
start()
```

Comment: I've run your code and it works correct. Please test your code again and add more info about your problem, platform and tools.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I've tested it a lot and here we go again. Generator does a number, I "guess" it and type 'y' to play once more, but it's the same number generated again!

Comment: Your code is correct and has correct behavior on my machine. what is your running environment?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you generate a new random number when you didn't guess right? Also, recursively calling `begin` is a bad idea: it will give an error after 1000 calls, and will make the flow of your program unnecessarily complicated to follow if it ever gets more complex. Use a loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works perfectly fine and so you genuinely must just have had incredibly good/bad luck (depending on which way you think about it). Try running the code in a different IDE - it's the only thing I can think of that may be causing the issue. Try running the script again?